# MSSQL Error 'The underlying provider failed on Open' IIS deployment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis, asp.net-web-api

Hello i have an API webservice using entity framework runing without problem, but when i deploy it in iis in the same machine i got this execption:

```
Exception: The underlying provider failed on Open.Inner Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'GRUPOTOTAL99\\GTLTSISW13W10$'.\r\n   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)\r\n   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\nClientConnectionId:9a382a4d-6baf-47f6-8283-f9eb07d6c73d\r\nError Number:18456,State:1,Class:14","data":null,"result":0}
```

It says login failed, is there any options or configuration file  that i can change to make it work?

Here is my connection string using windows authentication

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AutogestionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EntityDB.csdl|res://*/Models.EntityDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.EntityDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.215\devinst01;initial catalog=Autogestion;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: You need to create a login for your API's application pool in SQL server.

Comment: Are the database and IIS in the same machine? As @Usama Aziz said, you need to create a login for identity of application in SQL. You can also try to delete integrated security=True and add user and password who has sysadmin permissions in connectionstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a login for your API's application pool in SQL server.